# How to add custom price using meta?

Tags: wordpress

I try to add my custom price for products in cart

I tried to convert the prices and set them as the new price

```
$admin_price = (int)get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_admin_price ', true);

// Loop through cart items
foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    $cart_item['data']->set_price($admin_price);//don't work
    $cart_item['data']->set_price(50);//working
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$admin_price` ? is it returning the needed result?

Comment: soled it, below is the solution